# how to remove method of class by its signature from jar

Tags: android, android-proguard

I'd like to forbid using of one method from library at my project removing it from jar (and throing compile error).

For example we have

```
public class UtilClass {
    public int method(int param){
        //some stuff
    }

    public int method(int param1, int param2){
       // some stuff
    }
}
```

I need to forbid `UtilClass::method(param: int)` but still to allow `UtilClass::method(param1: int, param2: int)`

How can I do it using proguard?

Comment: add code and error logs

Comment: Is `UtilClass#method(int)` a method that your library uses internally? Can you make it package-private?

Comment: @DeeV this is a 3rd party component. I cannot change this class